# Hibernate ManyToMany: doesn't insert the same ID in both tables

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a (classic) many to many relationship using Hibernate and a Oracle database.

I defined my entities as follows.

Student.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Student implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
private Long studentId;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_PROJECT", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID") })
private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
```

Project.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Project implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="PROJECT_ID")
private int projectId;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="projects")
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
```

I have a `STUDENT_PROJECT` table in my oracle database that consists of two fields, `PROJECT_ID` and `STUDENT_ID` with a `composite primary key` on them.

I have a sequence on my `STUDENT` table to auto generate their `ID`.

```
TRIGGER STUDENT_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT ON STUDENT
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
 SELECT STUDENT_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL
 INTO   :STUDENT_ID
 FROM   dual;
END;
```

Now my problem is that when I try to persist my `Student` entity, the `ID` field of the `STUDENT` table doesn't correspond to the `STUDENT_ID` field of `STUDENT_PROJECT` table.

Somehow it persists an ID for Student and a different one in the mapping table and I can't figure out why.

This is how I manipulate my objects

```
    Student student = new Student();

    // set some fields

    Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();

    // call to a private method to set its projects

    student.setProjects(projects);
    studentDao.persist(student);
```

I had to remove the `foreign key` in the `STUDENT_PROJECT` table on the `ID` of `STUDENT` (else the constraint wouldn't let me save of course) to finally notice that is was setting differents `ID`'s but I don't understand why.

If you need more information let me know, I tried to keep it as small as possible, thanks.

UPDATE:

I have tried to remove the trigger on the `STUDENT` table and changed its Java configuration to

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "G1")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "G1", sequenceName= "STUDENT_SEQUENCE")
@Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
private Long studentId;
```

I now get: 
`javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session  : [fr.persistance.data.Student#3037]`

It doesn't save to database at all and produces the above exception on the `persist()`, I guess I have a problem with my sequence as it seems it tries to persist two `Student` objects with the same `ID` (I am looping to save multiples students and their projects).

I have used the eclipse debug to inspect a few of my `Student` objects after the `persist()` call and they each have a different `studentId` in Java but once the loop and the transaction end, the exception occurs but it does seem like they each get a separate ID.

Comment: Thisis because you already have Students in your database with conflicting ids. Remove all the students if they are just test data. Or configure your sequence to start with a higher number than the highest in your database.

Comment: No, both my STUDENT and my STUDENT_PROJECT tables are empty.

Also, I have inspected a few of my Student objects after the .persis() and they each have a different ID, the exception happens once the transaction ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Ids of the students are generated by the database in a trigger, while Hibernate tries to create the value itself.

For an oracle database, `GenerationType.AUTO` will use a sequence. The sequence is accessed by Hibernate, which assigns the value (before the student is actually inserted in the database).

To make Hibernate use your sequence, add

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence-generator", sequenceName = "STUDENT_SEQUENCE")
```

and remove the trigger.

When you want to use a trigger, you need to map it as `GenerationType.IDENTITY`. (Not recommended though.)

Comment: It must be something like that yes, but I don't have any trigger on my Join Table and I did not create an entity for it either in Java so I really don't understand where this is coming from.

Comment: You have the trigger for the Students. Hibernate assignes an ID, but you replace it with the trigger. Hibernate cannot know this and keeps using its own ids when adding references to students.

Comment: Accepting your answer, my problem was part what you said and the other part was that I needed to add the allocationSize for the cache on the sequence as such @SequenceGenerator(name = "G1", sequenceName = "STUDENT_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 500)

As I was inserting ~ 400 records at a time it was probably overflowing the cache, thanks.